# Snowflake Execute button not appearing in VS Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, sql

Apologize if this is a silly question. I use VS studio to connect to snowflake. And all of a sudden when I'm coding, no execute button appears to click. Sometimes I can get it to appear but then it's 50 50 on whether it actually will work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I tried reinstalling the snowflake connector, VS studio and restarting my computer

Comment: Hello, which extension? This one? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=snowflake.snowflake-vsc It got an update today. Did you verify the changelog if they removed/moved the button?

Comment: Yes its that extension. But that's not it. Documentation says there should be an execute button. When I launch I can run 1 query before the button either disappears or completely stops working. I'm at a loss

Comment: Could very well be a bug then, I'd rather contact their support.

Comment: Where would you advise is the best place to submit?

Comment: There's a homepage button on the website linked above. I'd look for contact there